# Can a single power supply control multiple relays?

Tags: power-supply, switches, relay

I want to make this circuit, to convert a toggle switch to a momentary switch:

[image]

I'll be using a 5V power source & relay, rather than 12v (with a higher μF capacitor).

Is it possible to use the same power supply (USB: 5v DC) to create multiple circuits like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a 5V supply - you must use 5V relay also, not 12V one.

Better not increase the capacity, but use a separate capacitor for each relay. You can still use just one main switch, make sure it's strong enough to withstand the sparks on discharging capacitors if you have many of them.

And you'll need a really powerful supply if you'll use many capacitors. And capacitor recharge times will affect the frequency of switchings you can achive.

You can add resistors to the capacitors and calculate the recharging time as per RC-circuit principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Sorry if I worded my question badly, I'll be using a 5v power supply *and* a 5v relay. I actually want to make this circuit for multiple switches. Imagine the circuit above * 5 (with 5 switches, 5 relays and 5 capacitors). Would that work on one 5v DC power supply?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work. As long as you don't need to switch all relays simultaneously — you don't even need a powerful supply.